# Telegram bot создание списка с уникальными значениями

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем привет!
я только начал изучать программирование и поставил себе задачку с телеграм ботом:
суть в том, что я хочу создать заполняемый список (регистрация пользователей через телеграм бота), но в случае, если пользователь уже регистрировался, то возвращается сообщение об этом, а допустим в 12 часа ночи, список должен быть очищен.
Пытаюсь это реализовать теми знаниями, которые получил, но пока успеха не добился.
Сейчас бот работает, до момента, когда возвращается ошибка о том `bot.register_next_step_handler(check_fullname(message))`, что пользователь уже зареган, дальше бот крашится)
Прошу помощь, в какую сторону копать

```
def q_fn(message):
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите своё ФИО в формате "ИвановИИ:',)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, check_list)

def check_list(message):
    if message.text in users_info:
        users_fullname.append(message.text)
        print(users_fullname)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(check_fullname(message))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите марку и номер автомобиля:')

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверные данные, повторите сначала /start')

def check_fullname(message):
    if message.text in users_fullname:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уже зарегистрированы', )
```

В дальнейшем хочу чтобы полученные данные выгружались в excel и направлялись по электронной почте.

Answer (score 0):

Про выгрузку в Excel (.xls) хз, про отправку на почту - посмотрите на smtplib (https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html).

Судя по вашей функции q_fn, функция register_next_step_handler требует два аргумента. Вы же передали в ошибочной строке только один аргумент - check_fullname(message).